# Maximum Likelihood, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm writing code, that executes MLE. At each step, I get gradient at one point and then move along it to another point. But I have problem with determination of magnitude of the move. How to determine the best magnitude for good convergence? Can you give me an advice how to avoid other pitfalls, such as presence of several maximums?

Comment: Do you have some code to look at? That's what SO is meant for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the presence of several maxima: this issue will occur when dealing with a function that is not [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function). It can be partially solved by multi-start optimization, which essentially means that you run the simulation multiple times in order to find as many maxima as possible and then selecting the 'highest' maximum from among them. Note that this does not guarantee global optimality, as the global optimum might be hard to reach (i.e. the local optima have a larger domain of attraction).

Regarding the optimal step size for convergence: you might want to look at back-tracking linesearch. A short explanation of it can be found in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373868/gradient-descent-optimal-step-size)

We might be able to give you more specific help if you could give us some code to look at, as jkalden already pointed out.

Comment: Code is here (parameter num_all equals 23): https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=24B240F1B6A69AFA!106&authkey=!AIlCLScaZt52Qcs&ithint=file%2cm